# How to prevent Qt slider from moving when it is not clicked

Tags: qt

I have a slider, and I aim to configure it so that upon a left-click, the slider value is captured, and subsequent actions can be taken based on that value. However, in my current implementation, I've noticed that when I click on the slider, it continues to move even after the mouse click is released. How can I prevent the slider from moving once it has been clicked?
Here is the code I have:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject* /*unused*/, QEvent* event) override {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
            auto* mouseEvent = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton && !slider_->isSliderDown()) {
                auto normalized_position = double(mouseEvent->pos().x()) / double(slider_->width());
                auto value = slider_->minimum() + ((slider_->maximum() - slider_->minimum()) * normalized_position);

                slider_->setValue(static_cast<int>(value));
                slider_->sliderReleased();
                slider_->setSliderDown(false);

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: By default, pressing on the "groove" repeats a `SliderPageStepAdd` (or `SliderPageStepAdd`), so the solution is to call the default `mouseReleaseEvent()` implementation. Note that the value you are getting will probably be inaccurate, since the slider does not use the whole width (or height) for its value range. Consider using [`QStyle::sliderValueFromPosition()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#sliderValueFromPosition) which is what QSlider actually does.

Comment: Do you mean instead of ```if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease){}```, call the default ```mouseReleaseEvent()```? But then how/where can I capture slider value?

Comment: No, I mean just call the default `slider_::mouseReleaseEvent(event)` (not sure about the syntax, I don't know how to properly write in C++) *and then* do the rest.